# Google Maps Dynamic Styled Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

since the V2 markers are depreciated from here.

https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons#plain_pin

Is there an alternative to this for V3? I am really not needing anything fancy. I just need a regular marker but with the ability to assign its color via RGB or Hex? Does this exist or possible?

The other day I found a page on the Google Docs with all the icons you could use and call by name and those would probably work but I can't find that link now.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some more digging I found a really nice site that has a lot of custom icons and where you can even design your own with your own colors, letters etc.

http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/